# Decoupling development-server and internet

Tags: security

I am working in a small set-up where there are 4 developers (might grow to 6 or 8 in cuople of years). I want to set-up an environment in which developers get an internet access but can not share any data from the company on internet. I have thought of the following plan:

1. Set-up a centralized git server (Debian). The server will have an internet access. A developer will only have git account on that server, and won't have any other account on it.
2. Do not give internet access to developer's individual machine (Windows XP/Windows 7).
3. Run a virtual machine (any multi-user OS) on the centralized server (the same one on which git is hosted). Developer will have an account on this virtual machine. He/she can access internet via this virtual machine.
   Any data-movement between this virtual machine and underlying server, as well as any of the developer's machine, is prohibited.
4. All developers require USB port on their local machine, so that they can burn their code into a microcontroller. This port will be made available only to associated software that dumps the code in a microcontroller (MPLAB in current case). All other softwares will be prohibited from accessing the port.
5. All USB ports associated with the server will be made available only to VM running on it, by default. This will enable developers to move their personal data between their USB-stick and VM/internet.

As more developers get added, providing internet support for them will become difficult with this plan as it will slow down the virtual machine running on the server. Can anyone please suggest a better alternative ? Are there any obvious flaws in the above plan ?

Some key details of a prospective server are as below: 1) OS:Debian 2) RAM: 8GB 3) CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1220v2 4C/4T

PS: The question was asked on other forum from Stack-Exchange (super-user). Since I found that it is an inappropriate place to ask this question, I have removed it from their and am asking it here.

Comment: In other words, you want to create an environment that absolutely sucks to work and develop in, e.g. because it's unnecessary hard to get help from sites like [SO], effectively costing you money due to lost time. As usual, it's a bad idea to try to solve a social problem with a technical "solution".

Comment: As I told you the last time you posted this, the solution is a company policy and a lawyer.

Comment: What is your budget for this project ?

Comment: @SvW: Your summary of the situation is incorrect. We are nowhere restricting developers from accessing internet hence any line of thought that follows this assumption is not valid.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks for a suggestion! Those things are in progress indeed. We are taking precaution to avoid the incidence at the first place. On a side note, effectiveness of those things depends on speed of judiciary system in that part of the World, which unfortunately is not great in part of the World where this system will be deployed.

Comment: @Iain: Currently it is 10k USD. Might get doubled in near future. This might sound very low, but for next five years company is not willing to grow this team beyond 8 employees.

Comment: @intoxicated.roamer: You are restricting people from working effectively. Having the internet session completely separate and not being able to copy/paste code snippets etc. would drive me nuts pretty fast and either your project or your pay scale would have to be really compelling to prevent me from running away from such a work place as fast as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Michael is right.  You need a bulletproof **company policy first**, and a legal team to enforce it.

However, there are some things that can be done to give you some tradeoff between security and usability.

A good first move would be to **hire a network architect with a good security background.**

However, the theory is this:

Firstly, separate your network into two physical segments, one for company proprietary, and one for public domain.

On these two information domains, you have separate computers, and a KVM for each desk, so that they don't need 4 monitors, just 2..

Inside your Proprietary network, you have things like your development, test and build environments, internal Git server and so on.

On the Public network, you have things like Exchange, Web Proxy, and so on.

You'll need a very secure web proxy to allow you to intercept and filter HTTPS traffic, so that you can perform deep packet inspection to look for things that look like company proprietary material.

You'll have to find some software which will intercept data being copied to USB devices and network shares, and inspect that for company proprietary data being copied in either direction, and block the transfer if proprietary data is moved into the public domain.

Your public network should be protected from the internet by a double skin, differing vendor firewall, with a DMZ for the outbound traffic, and a sophisticated next-generation firewall which is focussed on application traffic flows, rather than stateful port blocking.

Once you've got it set up, hire an accredited penetration test company to assess your network, and then based on their recommendations, further secure your network.

Oh, and money.  You're gonna need lots of money, both to pay the consultant, and the legal team, and to buy the sophisticated firewall and inspection technology.

Comment: Thanks Tom O'Connor for a detailed and insightful reply!

Comment: Also, Data Loss Prevention (DLP) software comes in really handy when you're not using two separate environments. And there's open source software available.

Comment: DeviceLock is Awesome for this.. Although not without it's drawbacks.